# PHP PDO get all row names as objects containing value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, row

I have a mySQL database table setup called `site`.

Rather than qet the column headings to produce a PHP object of values I want to produce data from the rows.

TABLE: `site`

```
:::field:::::value:::::

   url       www.example.com
   name      example site
   etc       Example Etcetera
```

So I want to be able to get this information from the server by calling the column name I want and the row I am after. I want to do this for all fields in `site` as I don't want to do multiple calls for the various different rows in `site`; I'd rather store all the information from the beginning in the object:

eg. `<? echo $site['url']; ?>`

I created this put it appears to be causing an error:.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `site`"; 
$site[];
foreach($sodh->query($sql) as $sitefield){
    $site[$sitefield['field']] = $sitefield['value'];
}
```

Obviously I've missed something. ¿Any idea as to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$site[];
```

should be

```
$site = array();
```

Comment: OK but that has not fixed the problem